# UIkit's modals in React: integration

Tags: reactjs, getuikit

I'm working on this project where the frontend is in React with UIkit for the user interface. The integration between the parts looks poorly implemented. I'm going to explain why. There is a `Modal` component, something like

```
export class Modal extends Component {
  static getByName = name => UIkit.modal(`[data-modal-name='${name}']`)

  static show = name => {
    const modal = Modal.getByName(name)
    if (modal) modal.show()
  }

  static hide = name => {
    const modal = Modal.getByName(name)
    if (modal) modal.hide()
  }

  render() {
    // a modal
  }
}
```

this is used in this way

```
export const LoginFormModal = props => (
  <Modal name="login-form" className="login-form-modal" hideClose>
    <LoginForm />
  </Modal>
)
```

and show/hide is called programmatically where needed (even redux's actions)

```
Modal.hide("login-form")
```

this is in a Redux action, like this

```
export const login = credentials => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(showLoader())

    API.authentication.login(
      credentials,
      response => {
        setCurrentUser(
          Object.assign({}, response.user, { user_id: response.user.id })
        )
        Modal.hide("login-form")
        dispatch(loginSucceded(response))
        dispatch(hideLoader())
        dispatch(push("/"))
        dispatch(fetchNotificationsCounter())
      },
      error => {
        dispatch(loginFailed(error))
        dispatch(hideLoader())
      }
    )
  }
}
```

This seems to work. Until you leave a component. When you come back to it, the second time the programmatically hide does not work anymore.

Anyone can lead me to how integrate the parts in a more react-appropriate way?

Comment: is redux state work with this? can you add code sample with  your redux's actions.

Comment: Added a redux action as an example

Comment: It works the first time, my modal is closed programmatically. But, if I leave the component (unmount) e return to it, never works again.

Comment: you have to get state that indicate you have logged at `LoginFormModal`

Answer (score 4):

*Using the parts of uikit which manipulate the dom (show, hide) is obviously hard to connect with React (and probably you shouldn't), however:*

You need to move the call of the functions `show` and `hide` inside the Component by passing the bool of the state of the modal (eg. `modalopen`) . A good hook is the `componentWillReceiveProps` which can be used to check the previus props

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.modalopen !== this.props.modalopen) {
    if (nextProps.modalopen) {
      getByName(...).show()
    } else {
      getByName(...).hide()
    }
  }
}
```

(this is inside the Modal class)

Comment: You probably doing something similar for your loaded (assumption based on the `showLoader` and `hideLoader` in the dispatcher)

Answer (score 2):

The thing I don't like and that is definitely not a "React-way" is that the code is mutating state directly from an action creator (!). From [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs):

> For example, instead of exposing open() and close() methods on a
>   Dialog component, pass an isOpen prop to it.

So what if you had one modal that would be controlled by the redux state? Here is a possible implementation:

**ModalWindow** - will react to state changes and render depending what's in store:

```
import React from 'react';
import InfoContent from './InfoContent';
import YesOrNoContent from './YesOrNoContent';
import { MODAL_ACTION } from './modal/reducer';

class ModalWindow extends React.Component {
  renderModalTitle = () => {
    switch (this.props.modalAction) {
        case MODAL_ACTION.INFO:
          return 'Info';
        case MODAL_ACTION.YES_OR_NO:
          return 'Are you sure?';
        default:
          return '';
    }
  };

  renderModalContent = () => {
    switch (this.props.modalAction) {
      case MODAL_ACTION.INFO:
        return <InfoContent />;
      case MODAL_ACTION.YES_OR_NO:
        return <YesOrNoContent />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
        this.props.isModalVisible ?
        <div>
           <p>{this.renderTitle()}</p> 
           <div>
              {this.renderModalContent()}
           </div>
        </div>
        :
        null
    );
  }
}

export default connect((state) => ({
    modalAction: state.modal.modalAction,
    isModalVisible: state.modal.isModalVisible,
}))(ModalWindow);
```

**modal reducer** it will expose API to show/hide modal window in the application:

```
export const SHOW_MODAL = 'SHOW_MODAL';
export const HIDE_MODAL = 'HIDE_MODAL';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  isModalVisible: false,
  modalAction: '',
};

export default function reducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_MODAL:
      return { ...state, isModalVisible: true, modalAction: action.modalAction };
    case HIDE_MODAL:
      return { ...state, isModalVisible: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const MODAL_ACTION = {
  YES_OR_NO: 'YES_OR_NO',
  INFO: 'INFO',
};

const showModal = (modalAction) => ({ type: SHOW_MODAL, modalAction });
export const hideModal = () => ({ type: HIDE_MODAL });
export const showInformation = () => showModal(MODAL_ACTION.INFO);
export const askForConfirmation = () => showModal(MODAL_ACTION.YES_OR_NO);
```

So basically you expose simple API in form of redux action-creators to control the state of your `ModalWindow`. Which you can later use like:

```
dispatch(showInformation())
...
dispatch(hideModal())
```

Of course, there could be more to it like optional configuration that would be passed to action creators or queue for modals.

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of a hook and a component for this.

Hook:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import UIkit from "uikit";

export default function useModal() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [ref, setRef] = useState(null);

  const open = (e) => {
    UIkit.modal(ref).show();
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  const close = (e) => {
    UIkit.modal(ref).hide();
    UIkit.modal(ref).$destroy(true);
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  return [setRef, isOpen, open, close];
}
```

Component:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";

const Modal = forwardRef(({ children, isOpen, full, close }, ref) => (
  <div
    ref={ref}
    data-uk-modal="container: #root; stack: true; esc-close: false; bg-close: false"
    className={`uk-flex-top ${full ? "uk-modal-container" : ""}`}
  >
    <div className="uk-modal-dialog uk-margin-auto-vertical">
      <button
        type="button"
        className="uk-modal-close-default"
        data-uk-icon="close"
        onClick={close}
      />
      {isOpen && children()}
    </div>
  </div>
));

export default Modal;
```

Consumption:

```
function Demo() {
  const [ref, isOpen, open, close] = useModal();
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="uk-button uk-button-default"
        onClick={open}
      >
        upgrade
      </button>
      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} close={close} ref={ref} full>
        {() => (
          <div>
            <div className="uk-modal-header">
              <h2 className="uk-modal-title">title</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="uk-modal-body">
                body
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Read more: https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html